# T-SQL process custom XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I need help to process custom XML. I put an excerpt below where I am looking to get all those values marked with blue lines. I'm confused because the attributes for each of the  could be different. I also attaching complete running code for testing.

I tried different approaches that I know but the vendor changed the schema and now I can't figure it out.

Thanks so much.

Looking to get all those values  also

[image]

marked with blue lines:

[image]

I just get this running  code which doesn't work properly yet,

```
DECLARE @xml XML = ('<Submission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Measures>
    <A100 versionID="A01">
      <Metadata>
        <TY_Year>2020</TY_Year>
        <Benefit>true</Benefit>
      </Metadata>
      <AnnualCount>
        <Stratification>
          <Pool>11-14</Pool>
        </Stratification>
        <Data>
          <RegTotal>13071</RegTotal>
          <CountA>542</CountA>
        </Data>
      </AnnualCount>
      <AnnualCount>
        <Stratification>
          <Pool>15-18</Pool>
        </Stratification>
        <Data>
          <RegTotal>12016</RegTotal>
          <CountA>458</CountA>
        </Data>
      </AnnualCount>
      <AnnualCount>
        <Stratification>
          <Pool>19-20</Pool>
        </Stratification>
        <Data>
          <RegTotal>4591</RegTotal>
          <CountA>129</CountA>
        </Data>
      </AnnualCount>
      <AnnualCount>
        <Stratification>
          <Pool>2-3</Pool>
        </Stratification>
        <Data>
          <RegTotal>5649</RegTotal>
          <CountA>127</CountA>
        </Data>
      </AnnualCount>
      <AnnualCount>
        <Stratification>
          <Pool>4-6</Pool>
        </Stratification>
        <Data>
          <RegTotal>8995</RegTotal>
          <CountA>366</CountA>
        </Data>
      </AnnualCount>
      <AnnualCount>
        <Stratification>
          <Pool>7-10</Pool>
        </Stratification>
        <Data>
          <RegTotal>11818</RegTotal>
          <CountA>546</CountA>
        </Data>
      </AnnualCount>
    </A100>
    <Z200 versionID="B12">
      <Metadata>
        <TY_Year>2020</TY_Year>
        <Benefit>true</Benefit>
      </Metadata>
      <Z200_Ratio>
        <Stratification>
          <Pool>12-18</Pool>
        </Stratification>
        <Data>
          <RegTotal>349</RegTotal>
          <X5>12</X5>
          <CountA>269</CountA>
          <CountB>0</CountB>
        </Data>
      </Z200_Ratio>
      <Z200_Ratio>
        <Stratification>
          <Pool>19-50</Pool>
        </Stratification>
        <Data>
          <RegTotal>911</RegTotal>
          <X5>192</X5>
          <CountA>520</CountA>
          <CountB>0</CountB>
        </Data>
      </Z200_Ratio>
      <Z200_Ratio>
        <Stratification>
          <Pool>5-11</Pool>
        </Stratification>
        <Data>
          <RegTotal>424</RegTotal>
          <X5>20</X5>
          <CountA>329</CountA>
          <CountB>0</CountB>
        </Data>
      </Z200_Ratio>
      <Z200_Ratio>
        <Stratification>
          <Pool>51-64</Pool>
        </Stratification>
        <Data>
          <RegTotal>590</RegTotal>
          <X5>456</X5>
          <CountA>336</CountA>
          <CountB>0</CountB>
        </Data>
      </Z200_Ratio>
    </Z200>
  </Measures>
</Submission>')



;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.ncqa.org/ns/2006/idss/hedis')
SELECT c.value('@id','VARCHAR(10)') AS msr
 --   , x.value('@id','VARCHAR(10)') AS  element
 --   , x.value('(value/text())[1]','VARCHAR(10)') AS Val
--INTO #t
FROM @xml.nodes('/submission/measures') AS t(c)
    CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('/submission/measures') as f(x);
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Thanks all for comments, I added my  self-icnlusive test snippet

Comment: @Mich28, the ##3-4 are still missing.

Comment: #3. Output values highlighted on the picture posted #4. Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU22) (KB4577467)  Tx YItzhak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<Submission xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Measures>
        <A100 versionID="A01">
            <Metadata>
                <TY_Year>2020</TY_Year>
                <Benefit>true</Benefit>
            </Metadata>
            <AnnualCount>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>11-14</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>13071</RegTotal>
                    <CountA>542</CountA>
                </Data>
            </AnnualCount>
            <AnnualCount>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>15-18</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>12016</RegTotal>
                    <CountA>458</CountA>
                </Data>
            </AnnualCount>
            <AnnualCount>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>19-20</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>4591</RegTotal>
                    <CountA>129</CountA>
                </Data>
            </AnnualCount>
            <AnnualCount>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>2-3</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>5649</RegTotal>
                    <CountA>127</CountA>
                </Data>
            </AnnualCount>
            <AnnualCount>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>4-6</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>8995</RegTotal>
                    <CountA>366</CountA>
                </Data>
            </AnnualCount>
            <AnnualCount>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>7-10</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>11818</RegTotal>
                    <CountA>546</CountA>
                </Data>
            </AnnualCount>
        </A100>
        <Z200 versionID="B12">
            <Metadata>
                <TY_Year>2020</TY_Year>
                <Benefit>true</Benefit>
            </Metadata>
            <Z200_Ratio>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>12-18</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>349</RegTotal>
                    <X5>12</X5>
                    <CountA>269</CountA>
                    <CountB>0</CountB>
                </Data>
            </Z200_Ratio>
            <Z200_Ratio>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>19-50</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>911</RegTotal>
                    <X5>192</X5>
                    <CountA>520</CountA>
                    <CountB>0</CountB>
                </Data>
            </Z200_Ratio>
            <Z200_Ratio>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>5-11</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>424</RegTotal>
                    <X5>20</X5>
                    <CountA>329</CountA>
                    <CountB>0</CountB>
                </Data>
            </Z200_Ratio>
            <Z200_Ratio>
                <Stratification>
                    <Pool>51-64</Pool>
                </Stratification>
                <Data>
                    <RegTotal>590</RegTotal>
                    <X5>456</X5>
                    <CountA>336</CountA>
                    <CountB>0</CountB>
                </Data>
            </Z200_Ratio>
        </Z200>
    </Measures>
</Submission>';
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT r.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS [Msr]  
    , c.value('(Stratification/Pool/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS [Pool]
    , c.value('(Data/RegTotal/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [RegTotal]
    , c.value('(Data/X5/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [X5]
    , c.value('(Data/CountA/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [CountA]
    , c.value('(Data/CountB/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [CountB]
FROM @xml.nodes('/Submission/Measures/*[@versionID="B12"]') AS p(r)
    CROSS APPLY p.r.nodes('Z200_Ratio') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+------+-------+----------+-----+--------+--------+
| Msr  | Pool  | RegTotal | X5  | CountA | CountB |
+------+-------+----------+-----+--------+--------+
| Z200 | 12-18 |      349 |  12 |    269 |      0 |
| Z200 | 19-50 |      911 | 192 |    520 |      0 |
| Z200 | 5-11  |      424 |  20 |    329 |      0 |
| Z200 | 51-64 |      590 | 456 |    336 |      0 |
+------+-------+----------+-----+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks much YItzhak!!   I will have more nodes like 'Z200_Ratio' but I will try to figure it out how to expand your code.

Comment: @Mich28, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer. Please up-vote: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali

Comment: Thanks again Yitzhak